# Registry Creation With Dynamic Key Name

Tags: c++, multithreading, registry

TL;DR: I wish to create a registry with a dynamic lpSubKey parameter.

I have a program that creates n threads iteratively and passes the value of current iteration to the thread. Each thread then creates a registry using RegCreateKeyEx function. I want to make it so each thread will create a key ending with it's iteration number (e.g. thread no 7 will create a registry key at "HKEY_CURRENT_USER/XXXX/ThreadRegistry7"). I could not find a way to do it as I could not cast a concatenation of a string and a number to a LPCTSTR type.

I have searched around for 2 days and tried many different approaches but could not seem find a solution to achieve this.

On a side note: My code seems to lose track of "param" passed to the threads after the first one as their "index" parameter get assigned to numbers such as "255020768".

```
// Creates a new registry or opens it if it already exists
HKEY createRegistry (int index){
    HKEY created_registry = NULL;
    DWORD reg_created_status;
    DWORD reg_disposition = 0;

    reg_created_status = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
                                    TEXT("AAAA\\Registry%d\0",&index),
                                    0,
                                    NULL,
                                    0,
                                    KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
                                    NULL,
                                    &created_registry,
                                    NULL);

    if (displayMessage(reg_created_status) == true){

        if (reg_disposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY){
            std::cout << "A new registry has been created";
        }
        else if (reg_disposition == REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY){
            std::cout << "Opened an existing registry";
        }
    }

    return created_registry;
}



// Thread that creates, modifies and closes the same registry until main process exits
DWORD WINAPI RegModifierThread (LPVOID param){
    HKEY regKey = NULL;
    int toggle_value = 1;
    int* thread_number_addr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(param);
    int thread_number = *thread_number_addr;

    while(1){
        regKey = createRegistry(thread_number);
        modifyRegistry(regKey,toggle_value,thread_number);
        closeRegistry(regKey,thread_number);
        regKey = NULL;
        toggle_value = 1 - toggle_value;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }

    return 0;
}


HANDLE createThread (int index){
    int* index_addr = &index;
    HANDLE hThreadModifier;

    hThreadModifier = CreateThread(NULL,0,*RegModifierThread,index_addr,0,NULL);
    return hThreadModifier;

}
```

I would appreciate any answer that would point me in the right direction.

Best regards

Comment: Sounds like a rather poor design TBH. The registry is not a place to dump random data. What's wrong with a `std::map<int, Foo>` ? Sure, that's not persistent, but your threads are also rather ephemeral.

Comment: The goal is to specifically create a script that will generate multiple threads that continuously write to different registry keys and exit when a button is pressed in the main process; it will be used to perform certain stress tests.  

Regarding my code; I'm not really familiar with c++ and may have violated multiple good practices, but this will be used offline so I just tried to get a working script as fast as I can.

Comment: What exactly do you think you're stressing, and how do you expect that component to fail under stress?  (Note: answering "the Windows registry code" and "performance degradation" are not correct answers, as the Windows registry is not designed for high-performance rewriting of the same registry key. )

Comment: I will check if data corruption occurs in a power loss event during read/write operation. But I don't see how this is related to my original question: Is it possible to create dynamically created registry key names?